# Auto on/off 12v DC timer for garden irrigation

Tags: irrigation

I have 7 raised garden beds with irrigation setup. Irrigation consists of a 100w solar panel going into a 120w max Controller. This charges 2 12v DC batteries connected in parallel. The batteries are used to power a 400gph water transfer pump which pulls water from my rain collection system when manually connected.

I have been trying to find a DC timer (as AC is not available and an inverter would kill the batteries) that will automatically turn on the pump at a set time then turn it off after a set time frame has passed with at least 2 on/off per day.

Does anyone have any suggestions on a timer that I can use for this purpose? It will be located outside but can be installed in a element tight enclosure if needed.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Really, the usual battery timer (with 9 V battery inside) should be good for a year.

Comment: Cross-post of https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/252750/38002

Comment: Was instructed to post here as well as my original location.

Comment: This is for turning the pump on/ off, not the water.

Comment: There are battery and/or solar (some solar with ultra-capacitors rather than batteries, that may live longer) irrigation controllers commonly available. You just need to use the output of one to operate your pump, (via a relay, usually) rather than to operate a valve. I don't think they actually care what they are operating.